# Filter json file by matching word

Tags: grep

i have this json:
[
  {
    "id": 36,
    "name": "admin-key",
    "role": "Admin",
    "expiration": "2020-05-07T12:02:09Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 35,
    "name": "tmp",
    "role": "Admin",
    "expiration": "2020-05-07T12:01:24Z"
  }
]

And i need to filter by "admin-key" to obtain desired result :
36

Comment: Use [tag:jq] instead, grep is a line oriented tool and can't parse JSON syntax-wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the solution: 
| jq '.[] | select(.name|test("admin-key")) | .id'